# Laravel 4 SQL log / console

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there something similar in Laravel that allows you to see the actual SQL being executed? 
In Rails, for example, you can see the SQL in console. In Django you have a toolbar.

Is there something like that in Laravel 4?

To clarify: My question is how to do it without code. Is there something that is built-in in Laravel that does not require me to write code in app?

**UPDATE**: Preferably I'd like to see CLI queries as well (for example `php artisan migrate`)

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Laravel 4, use this:

```php
$queries    = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

Comment: The OP didn't like this answer, but it sure just stopped me from having to ask a question. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I do this in Laravel 4.

Just set it once in `app/start/global.php` or anywhere but make sure it is loaded and then it will start logging all your SQL queries.

```php
Event::listen("illuminate.query", function($query, $bindings, $time, $name){
    \Log::sql($query."\n");
    \Log::sql(json_encode($bindings)."\n");
});
```

Comment: How did you configure Laravel/Monolog so that you could use \Log::sql() ? I'm having to use Log::info() and it logs to the default log file but I would like to log to a separate log file.

Comment: You don't need to configure anything actually.
as sql is not a function in "Log" class, it will be handled by __callStatic method which will use the called function name as Log Type (sql in my above example).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick Javascript snippet you can throw onto your master page template.
As long as it's included, all queries will be output to your browser's Javascript Console.
It prints them in an easily readable list, making it simple to browse around your site and see what queries are executing on each page.

When you're done debugging, just remove it from your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var queries = {{ json_encode(DB::getQueryLog()) }};
    console.log('/****************************** Database Queries ******************************/');
    console.log(' ');
    $.each(queries, function(id, query) {
        console.log('   ' + query.time + ' | ' + query.query + ' | ' + query.bindings[0]);
    });
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('/****************************** End Queries ***********************************/');
</script>
```

Comment: ...Dont forget to remove this one for production sites! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a Composer package for that: https://packagist.org/packages/loic-sharma/profiler

It will give you a toolbar at the bottom with SQL queries, log messages, etc. Make sure you set `debug` to true in your configuration.

Comment: As far as I see - it still requires you to write code. My question was how to avoid writing code - looking for something built-in.

Comment: Well that depends on what you mean by "write code". All you have to do is add `"loic-sharma/profiler": "dev-master"` in the `required` section in your `composer.json` and update composer.

Comment: That is obviously OK. What bothers me is that I have to write this: Profiler::startTimer('testLogging');

// The profiler listens to Laravel's logger.
Log::info('Hello World!');
Log::notice('Some event occured.');

Profiler::endTimer('testLogging');

Comment: That is only if you want to log messages, the profiler will automatically show you all SQL queries.

Comment: I tried adding and updating, but don't seem to be getting any messages in console when running migrations. Is that normal?

Comment: Oh, the profiler is web based so you can only see it in your browser. You should probably update your question and specify that you want it for the cli as well.

Comment: Still, thanks! :) Unless somebody offers something better - I think you have what I need.

Comment: That package is no longer maintained. Better to use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 4):

Here's another nice debugging option for Laravel 4:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a really simple way (if you are using `php artisan serve` and PHP 5.4) - add this to `app/start/local.php`:

```php
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    file_put_contents('php://stderr', "[SQL] {$sql} in {$time} s\n" . 
                      "      bindinds: ".json_encode($bindings)."\n");
});
```

but hoping to find a more official solution.

This will print SQL statements like this:

```
[SQL] select 1 in 0.06s
```

Comment: This is equally useful for `artisan tinker` as well. I just hope this will be in the core like Rails one day :) PS: Check if you are in `CLI` mode like `if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') { DB::listen(...`, otherwise browser requests may fill up `/var/log/apache2/error_log` with SQL logs.

Answer (score 1):

This code is directly taken form other source but i wanted to make it easy for you as follow  it worked for me on **PHPStorm** using my terminal window i was able to see a complete log but ,after **login** there was some **Sentry** thing.

1.add

`'log'=>true`

inside your `config/database.php` and below the place ur database name `ex.mysql`

then add below code to`routes.php` above all no under any route configuration , since u can make that under a give route configuration but , u only see when that route is called.

to see this output `/goto / app/storage/log/somelogfile.log`

```
if (Config::get('database.log', false))
{
    Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name)
    {
        $data = compact('bindings', 'time', 'name');

        // Format binding data for sql insertion
        foreach ($bindings as $i => $binding)
        {
            if ($binding instanceof \DateTime)
            {
                $bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
            }
            else if (is_string($binding))
            {
                $bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
            }
        }

        // Insert bindings into query
        $query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $query);
        $query = vsprintf($query, $bindings);

        Log::info($query, $data);
    });
}
```

Dont forget to make break point .... or ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

In QueryBuilder instance there is a method **toSql()**.

`echo DB::table('employees')->toSql()`

would return:

```
select * from `employees`
```

This is the easiest method to shows the queries.

Comment: This one is still working in 5.7 in Eloquent Method and raw method both.