# Laravel how to change date format in the list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We are retrieving the list from the database which is having date. We want to display it in different format. Suppose 10 Nov, 2014.

Here is my Code

Trail1:

```
$dropDown = Events::lists(DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%d %M, %Y'), 'id');
```

Trail 2:

```
$dropDown = Events::lists("DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m-%d')  AS event_date", 'id')
```

But it throws error. Is there any way that we can use, to get desired date format in Laravel?

Normal Query:

```
select id, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%d %M, %Y') AS event_date from events
```

Comment: Use of undefined constant event_date - assumed 'event_date'

Comment: I'm just guessing, but you could try `Events::lists(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT..."), 'id');`

Comment: @lukasgeiter tried it but no luck

Comment: @vvr did you try it with or without the ` AS event_date`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter tried in both ways

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL query it generates? Use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18236656/1903366) if you don't know how to do that...

Comment: @lukasgeiter sorry to disappoint you it is not printing query. Use of undefined constant event_date - assumed 'event_date'

Comment: @lukasgeiter when i gave a other query it is printing but this isn't. It is breaking at that particular point i think.

Comment: Query1 (I used like this): Events::lists(DB::raw(DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%d %M, %Y')), 'id')

Comment: Query2 (I used like this): Events::lists("DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%d %M, %Y') as event_date", 'id')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
Events::lists(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(event_date, "%d %M, %Y")'), 'id');
```

In the code you posted in the question (and the comments) there's always a small mistake.

1. DATE_FORMAT is an SQL function not a PHP function
2. You have to use `DB::raw` to be able to use SQL functions
3. `DB::raw` expects a string

Comment: the query is printing like this: select DATE_FORMAT(event_date, "%d %M, %Y"), `id` from `events`

Comment: is there any way that i can add as event_date or something like that

Comment: @vvr When using `lists` that wouldn't make much sense, because the return value is an array with id and value `[1 => "10 November, 2014"`