# How to use Eloquent ORM's getQueryLog() outside of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to figure out a way to log SQL queries from Eloquent ORM which I'm using within Zend Framework 1. I came across getQueryLog() method called in this manner:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

I found Illuminate\Database\Connection to contain the getQueryLog() method so I tried to do the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;

class IndexController
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // do stuff (e.g. fetch/update/create rows) 
        $questions = Questions::all()
        .
        .
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        var_dump($queries); exit;
        .
        // render view
    }
}
```

However, I get the following notice, and it returns NULL: `Notice: Undefined property: IndexController::$queryLog in /var/www/qasystem/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 918
NULL`

Can someone please suggest how I might use this outside of Laravel? I've searched online and can't see anything that I need to do different, although I suspect most examples will be used within Laravel. Also, is Illuminate\Database\Connection the correct class? Thanks

Comment: Does this work `Capsule::getQueryLog()`?

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: `Capsule::getQueryLog()` doesn't work. I'm not using Laravel, I'm using Eloquent within Zend Framework (1).

Comment: Does `Questions::getConnection()->getQueryLog()` work?

Comment: Did you got anything working? trying to find the same!

Comment: Hi @jtanmay, I think I ended up using PHP Debug Bar which is a really neat tool for viewing inline SQL queries and other debug stuff (similar to browser inspectors). Anyway I think for that I just required the PDO instance that is used in Eloquent which I obtained by `$conn = $anyEloquentModelObject->getConnection(); $pdo = $conn->getPdo();`. I guess from PDO object, somehow, you'll be able to get the SQL queries executed. Actually, looking at the previous comments, perhaps $conn->getQueryLog() will work when $conn is obtained this way. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`toSql`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) method instead. It will return you the final query command.

See [How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Even though a bit older- I just had the same issue, and using `toSql()` wasn't helping me as I have many-to-many relations and Eloquent executed more queries.

Based on @patricus' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998336/how-to-use-eloquent-orms-getquerylog-outside-of-laravel#comment44404873_27998336) I got it working like this:

```
function getTheThing() {
  (new Thing())->getConnection()->enableQueryLog();
  $thing = Thing::whereUid('something')
    ->with('AnotherThing')
    ->first();
  $loggedSqls = (new Thing())->getConnection()->getQueryLog();
  var_dump($loggedSqls);
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me using Illuminate\Database 8.7.1