# Unable to Print Raw SQL

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-5

I've tried various options. I just want to get the raw sql for this;

```
$payments = Payment::select('Vendor ZIP')->whereIn('Vendor ZIP', $postcodes)->get()->toArray();
```

I've tried;

```
//this
dd(array($payments)); 

//this one
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($payments)  
    { 
        dd(array($payments));
    });

//this one too
$sql = str_replace(['%', '?'], ['%%', "'%s'"], $payments->toSql());
$fullSql = vsprintf($sql, $payments->getBindings());
print_r($fullSql);
```

I mostly get a `No data received` error message on the browser. What else can I try?

The query is 100% correct by the way.

Comment: You have to call `toSql()` before `get()`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20382987/170403).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toSql` method to get the raw SQL query.

```
$payments = Payment::select('Vendor ZIP')->whereIn('Vendor ZIP', $postcodes)->toSql();
```