# Filter Pivot table conditionally with inverse relation - Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have roomConfigurations table like bellow,

```
id
roomTypeID
hotelId
```

Then Hotels table is like this

```
id
hotelNeme
```

Then Users table like this

```
id
userId
userName
passwd
```

Then hotel_user (Pivot) table like this

```
id
user_id
hotel_id
```

Now my question is, How can i get all records from roomConfigurations table  for selected user ?

I can do this using MySQL by joining tables, But i dont have any idea to do this in Laravel 5.

I would be very appreciate, if anyone can help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) should help here.

First, you need to make sure that `roomConfigurations` table has `id`, `room_type_id`, and `hotel_id` not `hotelId` because Laravel requires certain naming conventions.

But, guessing by what you've written so far, I think it'd be something like this:

```
class HotelUser extends Model {
    // so that we can get hotels from a user
    public function hotels () {
        return $this->belongToMany ('App\Hotel');
    }
}

class Hotel extends Model {
    // so that we can get users of a Hotel
    public function users () {
        return $this->belongsToMany ('App\HotelUser');
    }

    public function roomConfigurations () {
        return $this->belongToMany ('App\RoomConfiguration');
    }
}

class RoomConfiguration extends Model {
}
```

And then to use this it might be something like:

```
$userRoomConfigs = HotelUser::find(123)->hotels()->roomConfigurations();
```

Another, better, possibility might be [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

```
class HotelUser extends Model {
    public function roomConfigurations () {
        return $this->hasManyThrough ('App\RoomConfiguration', 'App\Hotel');
    }
}
```

And this would be used like so:

```
$userRoomConfigs = HotelUser::find(123)->roomConfigurations();
```

To help with your endeavor, check out [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string) which explains how to show the raw SQL queries that Laravel is making.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it is giving me what i want
`class roomConfigController extends Controller {`

```
public function index()
{
if(Auth::User()->role == 'client') {    
$roomConfigs = roomConfiguration::whereHas('hotels', function($query)
    {
        $query->whereHas('users', function ($query)
        {
        $query->where('users.id', Auth::User()->id);
        });
    })->where('is_delete', '=', '0')->get();
}
else {
    $roomConfigs = roomConfiguration::where('is_delete', '=', '0')->get();
}

//return $roomConfigs;
    return view('roomConfig.index',compact('roomConfigs'));
}
```