# laravel query builder always returns ? instead of value of variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 7.7.1 and in a query I pass a variable iaw the docs like so:

```
public function show($graad=3)
    {
        $sums=Sum::where(function ($query) use($graad) { 
            $query->where('graad',$graad);
            })->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->toSql();
```

Result is always:

```
"select * from `sums` where (`graad` = ?) order by RAND() limit 1"
```

So the variable is not passed in the correct way and converted to a "?".

Changing the value of $graad='test' or $graad='3' or even typehinting with

```
 public function show(int $graad=3)
```

does result in

```
 "select * from `sums` where (`graad` = ?) order by RAND() limit 1"
```

The column graad in the table is an int(11).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a security feature to prevent __sql injecttions__

Comment: Neither you nor the ORM are doing anything wrong. What you see is the expected result of the `toSql()` function. Please read all of [this](https://phptherightway.com/) before picking up a framework.

Comment: This is returning query instance. When you will pass the parameters, it will replace them in the place of ```?``` and execute on ```->get()``` function call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `get()`

try:

```
$sums = Sum::where('graad', $graad)->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get();
```

or

```
$sums = JOBS::where(function($query) use ($graad){        
    $query->where('graad', $graad);
})->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get();
```

```
public function show($graad)
{
   // Rest of your code
```

And then make sure your route is receiving the value in the url and sending along (Assuming this is how you are calling the method).

```
Route::get('your-route-name/{graad}', 'YourController@show');
```

Comment: That's not asked.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel under the hood uses Prepared Statements. This is to avoid SQL injection. The `?` is the placeholder for the data that will be substituted later by the bindings.

You can use 
`$query->getBindings();`
to fetch the data that will be binded in SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this below:

```
public function show($graad=3)
    {
        $sums=Sum::where(function ($query) use($graad) { 
            $query->where('graad',$graad);
            })->inRandomOrder()->limit(1);
        vsprintf(str_replace(['?'], ['\'%s\''], $sums->toSql()), $sums->getBindings());
```

Comment: Please don't teach people to perform SQL injections on themselves.

Comment: character "?" is placeholder for binding value of $graad, it is normal output and can not be changed. for complete explanation or solution for debugging, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372437/does-laravels-tosql-method-mask-ids-column-value-being-replaced-by-question

Comment: the answer of tesmojones was for me the right answer. Thanks all!