# Laravel: toSql function not displaying query correctly

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to diedump the query on my index screen using this line of code:

```
dd(DB::table('members')->where('name', '=', 'Tycho')->toSql());
```

Now the problem is that when I am displaying the query on my screen I get this:

```
"select * from `members` where `name` = ?"
```

My final goal of these lines of code is that I can save offline queries and execute them when the application is online. Unless someone has a solution for this, I'll have to save the queries in a database.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the `?` placeholders as Laravel uses [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

See [Ijas Ameenudeen's answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534386/639665) which details how to add a `toRawSql()` macro on the Eloquent builder which will replace the placeholders with the bindings that you supplied to the original query.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the `toSql` method, you can use the `getBindings` method to get the values / bindings.

oneliner:

```php
$query = DB::table('members')->where('name', '=', 'Tycho')->toSql();
// will give the raw query with bindings.
$sqlWithBindings = str_replace_array('?', $query->getBindings(), $query->toSql());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    DB::table('members')->where('name', '=', 'Tycho')->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```