# Laravel like query not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel "like" query doesn't work. For example, the query is as follows;

```
 $result = Sports::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
```

for example

```
$name= 'football';
```

If I use

```
$result->toSql();
```

It says

```
select * from sports`where ( `name` like ? )
```

It should be

`select * from sports where (`name`like '%football%' )` .

As you see , I can't see my item(football) in `like` query and only `?`.
I'm using Laravel version 4.2. What's wrong in query? and How can I fix it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: please ask properly question

Comment: please use proper formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The `?`s are just placeholders used parameterize the query. It helps prevent SQL injection. When the query is executed, they get replaced with the parameters you gave.

If you want to see the entire query, I'd recommend using `DB::getQueryLog()`. It'll show you an array with the query and the parameters used (in the `bindings` section of the array). Here's a reference to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236656/1193304

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 4.2, try out following code:-

```
$keyword= Input::get('keyword');

        return View::make('sports.search')
        ->with('result', Sports::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get())
        ->with('keyword', $keyword);
```