# NOTORM how to know sql query

Tags: php, notorm

in notorm documentation we know to get sql query use `(string) $table`
but i didn't get any result when use it.

```
$data = array('name'=>'testing','age'=>'25')
$result = $db->table->insert($data);
echo (string) $result ;
```

i know the query is `insert into table (name,age) values('testing','25');` i want to catch the query to variable. but `echo (string) $result` didn't show anything.

note:sorry for bad english

Comment: I have not used "NOTORM" before, but where is table defined?

Comment: @gerrit-luimstra table just name, it can change with another name of table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: @caoglish this question is for NOTORM, and your link is question for laravel

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you do `insert()`, `update()` or `insert_update()`, it will return last inserted row. So when you use `$result = $db->table->insert($data);` then `$result` will be an array. That's why you don't see anything. Try to use this:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";exit;
```

When you will use `select` it will return a SQL query. When you want to get `(string) $result` it should return primary key value. I'm not sure, but I haven't needed that query before, so probably it works just for `selects`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have not tried your suggestion... for now i write the query manually

Comment: Ok, if you ever find a solution, let me know too, I'm wondering about that one too, even I don't need it :)

Comment: `echo (string) $result` only work if $result is query to select table, so if `$result = $db->table()` and i use `echo (string) $result`, it showing **SELECT * FROM table**. not show anything if $result is query to insert like above

Comment: Yea, that's it. But it would be very useful to make this works also on INSERT or UPDATE for debugging purposes.