# Laravel 5.2 select data unknown variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, sqlbuilder

My function in controller for get data when user search ajax.

This is my code:

```
$receiptNum = Request::get('receiptNum');
// echo $receiptNum = 123456
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$q = DB::table('tbl_receipt AS r')
            ->join('company AS com', 'r.com_id', '=', 'com.com_id')
            ->join('branches AS b', 'com.b_id', '=', 'b.b_id')
            ->join('employee AS e', 'r.created_by', '=', 'e.e_id')
            ->where('r.receipt_code','=',$receiptNum)
            ->get();
$query = DB::getQueryLog();
var_dump($query);
```

I don't know what missing in my code, it's show raw sql like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM       "tbl_receipt" AS "r"
INNER JOIN "company"     AS "com" ON "r"."com_id" = "com"."com_id"
INNER JOIN "branches"    AS "b"   ON "com"."b_id" = "b"."b_id"
INNER JOIN "employee"    AS "e"   ON "r"."created_by" = "r"."e_id"
WHERE "r"."receipt_code" = ?
```

I trying to replace `$receiptNum` by num `123` for test, it's also show `?` in `raw sql`, please help me to solve it.

Comment: var_dump($receiptNum) before DB::connection what return?

Comment: it's return `123456`

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string

Comment: I think it's not problem with variable `$receiptNum` because when I replace my code with number `123` direct to SQL ,it's still show log `?` the same

Comment: yes, I try ready,it's still show `?` at SQL and sure `$receiptNum` have value. I search a lot a bout it but still not help

Comment: No, It isn't problem with variable because it will return error, but the ? is because query builder make a statement

Comment: with print_r( $query->getBindings() ); ?

Comment: if this solution resolved your problem, mark it, if other people have same problem can find solution.

Answer (score 1):

The "?" there are because it is a Statement.
If you want a string you have to replace.

I was inspired by https://gist.github.com/JesseObrien/7418983

and for example I make this.

```
    $q = DB::table('tbl_receipt AS r') 
->join('company AS com', 'r.com_id', '=', 'com.com_id') 
->join('branches AS b', 'com.b_id', '=', 'b.b_id') 
->join('employee AS e', 'r.created_by', '=', 'e.e_id') 
->where('r.receipt_code','=','123') ; 

$sql = $q->toSql(); 
// $bindings = $q->getBindings(); 
foreach($q->getBindings() as $binding) 
{ 
$value = is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'".$binding."'"; 
$sql = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $sql, 1); 
} 
var_dump($sql);
```