# Improve SQL queries speed

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I'm using MySQL and i have schema like:

```
|------------|-------------|------------|--------------|
|    cities  |category_city|  categories|   companies  |
|------------|-------------|------------|--------------|
|     id     |  city_id    |     id     |     id       |
|    name    | category_id |    name    |subcategory_id|
|            |             |  parent_id |    city_id   |
|            |             |            |...other cols |
|____________|_____________|____________|______________|
```

Relationships:
City with Category has `->belongsToMany()`

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Categories has subcategories:

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

And i'm getting companies from category and filtering by city, because i need the current city companies and for that i have a global scope:

```
 public function getCompanies($city_id)
    {
        return $this->companies()->whereHas('mainCity', function ($q) use ($city_id) {
            $q->where('city_id', $city_id);
        });
    }
```

**mainCity** method:

```
public function mainCity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
}
```

Here is my method performing the query with AJAX request:

```
public function getPlaces(City $city, Category $subcategory, $north, $south, $east, $west)
{
    $companies = $subcategory->companies()
        ->withCount('comments')
        ->companiesByBounds($north, $south, $east, $west)
        ->paginate(8);

    $markers = $subcategory->companies()
        ->companiesByBounds($north, $south, $east, $west)
        ->get(['lat', 'lng', 'slug', 'title']);

    return response()->json(['companies' => $companies, 'markers' => $markers], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

and by companiesByBounds scope method:

```
public function scopeCompaniesByBounds($query, $north, $south, $east, $west)
{
    return $query->whereBetween('lat', [$south, $north])
        ->whereBetween('lng', [$west, $east]);
}
```

In companies i have ~2m records. The main problem is that the queries taking 3.5 seconds. Help please to improve my queries.

Here is the query:

`` select count(*) as aggregate from `companies` where `companies`.`category_id` = '40' and `companies`.`category_id` is not null and `lat` between '53.68540097020851' and '53.749703253622705' and `lng` between '91.34262820463869' and '91.51600619536134' ``

Comment: Have you tried running the resultant SQL with EXPLAIN / the Visual Explain to look at the execution plan?

Comment: No, i didn't. How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with laravel, so dunno  if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string will get you the actual SQL query. If it does, then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html shows how to use EXPLAIN, and somewhere in MySQL Workbench is the Visual Explain.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `lat` and `lng` columns? Looks like you should add the indexes.

Comment: @StanislavL How can i check that?

Comment: Check the table indexes in your DB tool.

Comment: @StanislavL I dont really understand that. I have phpMyAdmin, i must do some query or what?

Comment: @StanislavL `CREATE INDEX idx_lat ON companies (lat);` - i must do something like this to add indexes?

Comment: Yes something like this

Comment: @StanislavL Looks like it's the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve speed you need to add indexes on the columns `lat` and `lng`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_lat ON companies (lat);
```

The indexes are used in queries when the columns are added to conditions.