# Lumen Database Queue first job always failing Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: queue, lumen

I have a very odd situation where I set up a job to run in my Lumen database queue and all but the first job is processed. I do keep getting this particular error:

```
[2017-12-12 22:07:10] lumen.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 702558208 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXX$
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXX/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(54): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleShutdown()
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
#2 {main}
```

I have tried allowing the memory limit to go up but I keep getting the same error with differing values for the exhausted memory.

I find it very odd that it is always the first job and all of the rest of the jobs run perfectly fine. Should I be looking for bad data in the first job?

My code basically looks like this:

**This is my Command file**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\UpdateNNNAppListJob;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Services\MiddlewareApi;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Mockery\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;

class AddEmailsToAppList extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'addemails:nnnmobileapp';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This will add all mobile app users in the database to the nnn mobile app list.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $chunkSize = 500; //this is the most middleware can handle with its bulk signup call
        $emailChunks = $this->getEmailsToAdd($chunkSize);
        $jobDelay = 120; //time between queued jobs
        $jobDelayTimeKeeper = 60; //This will be the actual time delay that will be put into the later method

        foreach ($emailChunks as $emailChunk) {
            Queue::later($jobDelayTimeKeeper, new UpdateMmpAppListJob($emailChunk));
            $jobDelayTimeKeeper = $jobDelayTimeKeeper + $jobDelay;
        }
    }

    public function getEmailsToAdd($chunkSize)
    {
        $emails = DB::table('app_users')
            ->join('app_datas', 'app_datas.customer_number', '=', 'app_users.customer_number')
            ->select('app_users.email')
            ->get()
            ->chunk($chunkSize);

        return $emails;
    }
}
```

**Here is my Job File**

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Services\MiddlewareApi;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Mockery\Exception;

class UpdateMmpAppListJob extends Job
{

    /**
     * Array of emails to update list with
     * @var array
     */
    protected $emailArray;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 2;

    public function __construct($emailArray)
    {
        $this->emailArray = $emailArray;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $listCodeToAddTo = 'NNNAPP';
        $sourceId = 'NNNNNNN';

        $middlewareApi = new MiddlewareApi();

        try {
            $middlewareApi->post_add_customer_signup_bulk($listCodeToAddTo, $this->emailArray, $sourceId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('An error occurred with theUpdateMmpAppListJob: ' . $e);
            mail('djarrin@NNN.com', 'UpdateNnnAppListJob Failure', 'A failure in the UpdateNnnAppListJob, here is the exception: ' . $e);
        }

    }

    public function failed(\Exception $exception)
    {
        mail('djarrin@moneymappress.com', 'Push Processor Que Failure', 'A failure in the UpdateMmpAppListJob, here is the exception: ' . $exception);
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions on this issue would be appreciate.

Comment: what if you do php artisan queue:work --once and check the failed jobs table

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I think the command should be ```php artisan queue:work --once --tries=1``` but it is worth to try

Also double check your sql query
You can use `->toSql()` to get raw sql query. Once I made sql join which take too many rows. ([Example of toSql() method use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382987/2728507)

Comment: @VaidasLungis you are right, I just wrote it without double checking it!

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I do get this exception after a failed job: A failure in the UpdateNnnAppListJob, here is the exception: Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXX/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php:394

the failed queue looks something like this: 
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\UpdateNnnAppListJob","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":2,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":

and the rest are just all of the user emails...

Comment: try php artisan queue:flush then re run the job with php artisan queue:work --once --tries=1

Comment: Is the exception thrown in your code? `Log::error('An error occurred with theUpdateMmpAppListJob: ' . $e);` should not work as you're passing in an object where string is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `->get()` which will load the entire result into memory. This causes the huge memory allocation that you're seeing. Remove it and let `->chunk(...)` work with the database builder instead of the in-memory Collection that get() has returned. You would also have to provide a callback to chunk that processes every chunk.

```
public function handle() {
    $chunkSize = 500; //this is the most middleware can handle with its bulk signup call
    $jobDelay = 120; //time between queued jobs
    $jobDelayTimeKeeper = 60; //This will be the actual time delay that will be put into the later method

    DB::table('app_users')
        ->join('app_datas', 'app_datas.customer_number', '=', 'app_users.customer_number')
        ->select('app_users.email')
        ->chunk($chunkSize, function($emailChunk) use (&$jobDelayTimeKeeper, $jobDelay) {
            Queue::later($jobDelayTimeKeeper, new UpdateMmpAppListJob($emailChunk));
            $jobDelayTimeKeeper = $jobDelayTimeKeeper + $jobDelay;
        });
}
```

Comment: that appears to throw the error: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chunk() must be callable, none given

Comment: You're right. I wasn't focusing on the syntax of the chunk invocation, but that the call to get() causes the entire result to be loaded. I've updated with an example on how the chunk callback works.

Comment: There was actually another error with that haha. The concept was correct though (it must be some sort of Laravel version difference error). I'm going to post the code that worked just for reference but you get the points @sisve

Answer (score 0):

The above concept is correct but this syntax was required to get past the

```
[2017-12-14 22:08:26] lumen.ERROR: RuntimeException: You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function. in /home/vagrant/sites/nnn/vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php:1877
```

This is for Lumen 5.5:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $chunkSize = 500; //this is the most middleware can handle with its bulk signup call
        $jobDelay = 120; //time between queued jobs
        $jobDelayTimeKeeper = 60; //This will be the actual time delay that will be put into the later method

        $emails = DB::table('app_users')
            ->join('app_datas', 'app_datas.customer_number', '=', 'app_users.customer_number')
            ->select('app_users.email')->orderBy('app_users.id', 'desc');

        $emails->chunk($chunkSize, function($emailChunk) use (&$jobDelayTimeKeeper, $jobDelay) {
            Queue::later($jobDelayTimeKeeper, new UpdateMmpAppListJob($emailChunk));
            $jobDelayTimeKeeper = $jobDelayTimeKeeper + $jobDelay;
        });
    }
```