# Laravel 5.4 query builder having issues with groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to convert this query to query builder in Laravel 5.4:

```
SELECT
    oc.id,
    oc.name,
    oat.user_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name
FROM
    oauth_clients oc
    LEFT JOIN oauth_access_tokens oat ON oc.id = oat.client_id
    JOIN users u on u.id = oat.user_id
    JOIN people p on p.id = u.person_id
WHERE oc.revoked = false AND oc.password_client = true
GROUP BY oc.id, oat.user_id
```

And getting this error barf: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/source/luniverse/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 648 and defined`
This is my attempt at it (one of many):

```
$tokens = DB::select('oc.id','oc.name','oat.user_id','p.first_name','p.last_name')
                ->from('oauth_clients as oc')
                ->leftJoin('oauth_access_tokens as oat', 'oc.id', '=', 'oat.client_id')
                ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'oat.user_id')
                ->join('people as p', 'p.id', '=', 'u.person_id')
                ->where('oc.revoked', '=', 'false')
                ->where('oc.password_client', '=', 'true')
                ->groupBy('oc.id')
                ->groupBy('oat.user_id')
                ->get();
```

The database config is set to strict mode, but that doesn't exactly seem to explain that particular error. The raw query runs fine in a DB gui.

Comment: The sql or the query builder? The sql query runs fine and gets exactly what I want.

Comment: output the built laravel select query, and compare it to your original, to try and find where the error is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string or just add this immediately before your query gets run: DB::listen(function ($query) {
   var_dump($query->sql);
    var_dump($query->bindings);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the groupby code like

```
$tokens = DB::select('oc.id','oc.name','oat.user_id','p.first_name','p.last_name')
            ->from('oauth_clients as oc')
            ->leftJoin('oauth_access_tokens as oat', 'oc.id', '=', 'oat.client_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'oat.user_id')
            ->join('people as p', 'p.id', '=', 'u.person_id')
            ->where('oc.revoked', '=', 'false')
            ->where('oc.password_client', '=', 'true')
            ->groupBy('oc.id','oat.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, though I had to match the select exactly, so more like: `->groupBy('oc.id','oc.name','oat.user_id','p.first_name','p.last_name')`

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select()` executes a query, you have to use `DB::table()`:

```
DB::table('oauth_clients as oc')
    ->select('oc.id','oc.name','oat.user_id','p.first_name','p.last_name')
```