# How can I write this raw mysql left join query using Laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I'm converting my web application to Laravel framework but I have a specific problem trying to write a particular raw SQL query in Laravel eloquent.

Here's the query:

What I've tried so far:

```
$cp = DB::table('career_progression')
->select('staff_id', DB::raw('MAX(cpEffectiveDate) as max_date'))
->groupBy('staff_id');

$staffs = DB::table('staff')
        ->leftJoinSub($cp, 'cp', function ($join) {
             $join->on('staff.id', '=', 'cp.staff_id');
        })
->select(DB::raw('staff.firstname, staff.middlename, staff.lastname, staff.state, staff.lga, cp.cpEffectiveDate, cp.designation, cp.grade, 
        cp.step'));
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.middlename, s.lastname, s.state, s.lga, cp.cpEffectiveDate,cp.designation, cp.grade, cp.step FROM staff s LEFT JOIN career_progression cp ON cp.staff_id = s.id JOIN (SELECT a.staff_id, MAX(a.cpEffectiveDate) AS max_date FROM career_progression a GROUP BY a.staff_id) x ON x.staff_id = cp.staff_id AND x.max_date = cp.cpEffectiveDate
```

Any hint/help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try DB::raw('raw query')->get() check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Should be `DB::select()` for raw query

Comment: What is the output query for `$staffs`? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236656/3226121)

Comment: Thanks guys. But when I do DB::select(), it doesn't accept any other collection, eg: ->where()

Comment: @Ijubadr this is what i get from dd-ing the result: Builder {#480 ▼
  #query: Builder {#479 ▶}
  #model: Staff {#437 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: array:4 [▶]
  #onDelete: Closure(Builder $builder) {#517 ▶}
  #passthru: array:13 [▶]
  #scopes: array:1 [▶]
  #removedScopes: []
}

Comment: Have you got models set up for these tables?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes