# Get raw sql query from belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How do I get raw sql like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1" from belongsToMany.

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_projects','project_id','user_id');
}
```

i tryed dd()

---

tryed this:

```
$query = $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_projects','project_id','user_id');
        dd($query->getQuery()->toRawSql(), $query->getBindings());
```

Output:

```
Users [{"id":2,"name":"My Name","email":"email@example.com","email_verified_at":null,"currant_workspace":1,"avatar":null,"created_at":"2019-08-31 04:35:20","updated_at":"2019-08-31 04:37:26","pivot":{"workspace_id":3,"user_id":2}}]
```

Comment: Temporarily get rid of the return and try `dd($this->belongsToMany(...)->toSql());` and see if you can view it there. Alternatively, look into enabling the query log in Laravel and view the queries as they are being run.

Comment: @TimLewis It prints data of table and pivot..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Get the Query Builder to Output Its Raw SQL Query as a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can print the query.

The `belongsToMany()` functions are done after the initial request. You may debug the queries you could do with the debugBar plug (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Hope this help