# Laravel 7 show insert query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert data into my DB, some of my data are stored, some others are not stored :

the dd() shows me that all data are ok :

```
array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "Texlm3Sx2zf0BBm0t2JF1chuIsvliuMHNVL8xH5g"
  "name" => "Dupont"
  "firstname" => "Robert"
  "team" => "ABC"
  "tel1" => "036303240"
  "tel2" => "123556567"
  "email" => "dupontlajoite@ABC.be"
  "password" => "12345678"
  "password_confirmation" => "12345678"
]
```

In MySQL, the record shows that I don't insert all information :

Team, tel1 and tel2 are NULL in my table, the others fields are stored (name, firstname...)

My question :

1.Is it possible to see the insert query to test it in PHPMyAdmin ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Get the Query Builder to Output Its Raw SQL Query as a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: Thank you Dekel.  I see this query select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1 because registration is ok and it makes another query (login)

Comment: So print the second query. Not sure I'm following... what is the issue?

Comment: That's solved, thank you.  I forgot to put fields into fillable (model).

Comment: You can mark this question as duplicate if this is the case.