# show all subjects offered by a student using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have done one-to-many relationships but when I loop through it in my view only one subject displays even when I have more than one subjects.

This is what I have done in my controller

```
$broadsheet = Broadsheet::with(['subject', 'session', 'term', 'student', 'classarm'])
                        ->where('session_id', $request->sessions)
                        ->where('term_id', $request->terms)
                        ->where('class_arm_id', $request->classarms)
                        ->selectRaw('sum(total) as totals, count(subject_id) as countrow, student_id, subject_id, session_id, term_id, class_arm_id, total')
                        ->groupBy('student_id')
                        ->orderBy('totals', 'desc')
                        ->get();
return view('broadsheet.index')->with('broadsheet', $broadsheet);
```

This is the index view

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
    
    {{--@foreach($broadsheet as $subjects) 
                      @foreach ($subjects->subject as $sub)
                          <th> {{ strtoupper($sub->subject->subject_name) }}</th>
                      @endforeach
                       
                     @endforeach--}}
    
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  
                     @foreach($broadsheet as $subject) 
                       <th> {{ strtoupper($subject->subject->subject_name) }}</th>
                     @endforeach 
                  
                  <th>TOTAL</th>
                  <th>AVERAGE</th>
                  <th>POSITION</th>
                  
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                       @foreach($broadsheet as $result) 
     
                    <tr>             
                        <td>{{ $result->total }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $result->totals }}</td>
                        <td>{{ number_format($result->totals/$result->countrow,2) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $result->exams }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $result->total }}</td>
                        
                      
    
                    </tr>
                     @endforeach 
                </tbody>
    
            </table>
    
    </div>
    @endsection
```

and this is my Broadsheet schema

```
class Broadsheet extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = [
        'student_id',
        'subject_id',
        'session_id',
        'term_id',
        'class_arm_id',
        'subject_total',
    ];


    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'student_id');
    }

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class, 'subject_id');
    }

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Session::class, 'session_id');
    }

    public function term()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Term::class, 'term_id');
    }

    public function classarm()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ClassArm::class, 'class_arm_id');
    }
}
```

I want to display students results like this
[Intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ8ne.png)

Please, I would really need assistance to get this working as any help would be greatly appreciated.I just started learning laravel recently. I don't really know where the issue is coming from

Comment: You can try to debug your query following this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string

Comment: I have tried using toSql() and the sql looks okay to me and yet I still get only one subject