# Which join is actually used behind the join() of laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I just want to know that which join will be used behind the scenes in Laravel join(). Either it is leftjoin(), rightjoin() or innerjoin() ?

For example:

What join will be used here actually?

```
$friends_votes = DB::table('users')
    ->join('votes', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('votes.user_id',1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: No, i'm asking about join() of laravel that what will be used behind the scenes by laravel.

Comment: What does that mean? There's only a single `join` method in Laravel. Why not start a debugger to check that?

Comment: I tried debugger and that was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

innerJoin see [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins):

and if you want [left or right join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause), you should strictly use them:

rightJoin:

```
$friends_votes = DB::table('users')
    ->rightJoin('votes', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
```

leftJoin:

```
$friends_votes = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
```