# Laravel Eloquent how to use && or AND inside single WHERE clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a query using Eloquent Model in Laravel.

My original query does not work

```
Query1::where('Course_ID', '=', $request->FLA)
->where('Date', '=', Carbon::today())
```

I would like the query to include both inside of a single WHERE, akin to:

`Query1::where('Course_ID', '=', $request->FLA && 'Date', '=', Carbon::today())`

Is this possible?

Comment: They would be functionally equivalent regardless of how you write it, chaining where conditions adds an AND in SQL.  Try debugging, see this answer for viewing the raw SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76600346/1583522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```php
Query1::where([
   'Course_ID' => $request->FLA,
   'Date' => Carbon::today()
]);
```

It will create the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Course_ID = ? AND Date = ?
```

But your approach, using two 'where's will have the same output

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your query written, using `->where()->where()` will generate the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM query_1 WHERE Course_ID = ? AND Date = ?
```

If you want your `WHERE` clause to be "scoped", you can use this syntax:

```php
Query1::where(function ($subQuery) use ($request) {
  return $subQuery->where('Course_ID', '=', $request->FLA)
  ->where('Date', '=', Carbon::today());
})->get();
```

This will generate the query:

```
SELECT * FROM query_1 WHERE (Course_ID = ? AND Date = ?)
```

*Notice the `()` around `Course_ID = ? AND Date = ?`*

This is useful when you want to add conditions that need to be grouped, i.e. if you were adding another `WHERE` that could conflict with the existing one(s).

Answer (score 0):

If your Date column is type of date, please try like that

```
Query1::where('Course_ID', '=', $request->FLA)->where('Date', '=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
```