# Laravel ORM method vs attribute

Tags: php, laravel-4

When dealing with Laravel's relations I often use something like this:

```
User::where(...)
      ->first()
      ->securityQuestions()
      ->take(2)
      ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
      ->get();
```

Note the use of `securityQuestions()` instead of `securityQuestions` that otherwise would raisethe error:

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()
```

Now, on other parts i get away with using:

```
User::where(...)
      ->first()
      ->securityQuestions
      ->contains(...)
```

Note the use of `securityQuestions` instead of `securityQuestions()`.

My guess is that in order to retrieve stuff (and keep chaining `wheres` and stuff) from the database you have to use the method while the attribute has an immutable resultset. Does anyone knows if that's right?

Comment: What is securityQuestions? A custom function? Or a table column?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange - If I were to guess, User has a one-to-many relation to SecurityQuestion.

Comment: Could you try to print the SQL that is being generated under the hood for both the queries by using DB::getQueryLog();? Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19085511/3007014. Then you can compare what's different.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange a model referencing the `security_questions` table, a many-to-many relation with the `users` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, 4 years later.

Basically `->securityQuestions()` is an [Eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections) while `->securityQuestions` is a [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

The former you can keep querying the database, the latter can't. Transforms over the former will hit the database, the latter won't.

Yes, I was right:

> My guess is that in order to retrieve stuff (and keep chaining wheres and stuff) from the database you have to use the method while the attribute has an immutable resultset. Does anyone knows if that's right?